# Updating a Record Collection Variables with Number Collection

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow, lightning-flow-builder

I have a question about a flow I am trying to implement, what I want from this flow is to assign an account to a lead in a random fashion. I've downloaded an apex action online that generates random numbers.

In the beginning of the flow, I fetch all of the accounts that has a certain checkbox checked and assign these accounts to a record collection variable, and then I loop through all of them generating a random number for each and putting each number in a collection variable. In the end of the loop I want to pick the one account that has the greatest random number and assign the lead to that certain account. I fill sort the accounts by the random number and only get the first one and assign accordingly.

However, I am having trouble making the connection between the random numbers and the accounts. When I debug the flow, I can see that the record collection variable as well as the random number collection variable is correctly populated. However, in the end I can't see anything when I create an update records element and choose the record collection variable.

Thanks for your help in advance!!

[flow looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Ygn.png)

Comment: Two approaches: 1) do it all in invocable apex; 2) add a custom field to Account called `Random_Number__c` - in your loop, set this field with an Assignment. Then  you have an association between Account and randomNumber.